# Cutting Strings Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have these strings that look like this.

```
NAME,"SAM"
NAME,"ADAM"
NAME,"ALEXANDER"
NAME,"SARAH"
```

I just need the actual name. For example, "SAM" for the first line. How do I cut the other parts of the string that i don't need? What function to use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you need `VBA` solution for this? Or did you miss the correct tag?

Comment: I just wanna know the syntax in vba to cut strings. Some sample codes would be good. I would try some code, but in this case i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this-

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(E9, FIND(",", E9, 1)), E9)
```

Where E9 is an example cell.

Basically we are searching for a comma (,) and then taking the right side of the text.

Are you writing VBA Code?

In which case use the following -

```
splitString= Split(<cellValue>, ",")
```

This will try to split the string based on the delimiter specified and return an array of values.

Edit 2:

```
Dim splitString() As String
splitString = Split(Range("F9").Value, ",")

If (UBound(splitString) > 0) Then
    Range("G9").Value = splitString(1)
End If
```

Comment: It returns "Find" not defined. 
This is what i typed:
Range("G9").Value = IfError(Right(E9, Find(",", E9, 1)), E9)

Comment: Okay, here is what i'm doing for now to test whether it works.
I have cell F9 containing NAME,"SAM". I've modified your code slightly to : Range("G9").Value = Split(Range("F9").Value, ","). This writes "NAME" to the cell G9. Am I doing this correctly? I need the right hand side of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of this:

Using `Split Function`(Evaluate is optional):

```
Dim mystring

mystring = Split([Sheet1!B2], ",")
[Sheet1!C2] = mystring(UBound(mystring))
```

Brackets `[]` are shortcut for `Evaluate Function`.
So it can be written like this as well:

```
mystring = Split(Evaluate("Sheet1!B2"), ",")
Evaluate("Sheet1!C2") = mystring(UBound(mystring))
```

Using `Right Function` plus `InStr or InStrRev` plus `Len` (Evaluate is optional):

```
[Sheet1!D2] = Right([Sheet1!B2], InStr([Sheet1!B2], ",") - Len([Sheet1!B1]))
```

`Evaluate` is optional. You can change it to conventional `Range object`, e.g. `Range("B2")`
Hope this helps.
Oh, you asked for syntax, see below:

```
Split(Expression As String,[Delimiter],[Limit As Long],[Compare As VbCompareMethod])
Len(Text)
Right(Text, [number of characters])
InStr([Start],[String1(where to search)], _
      [String2(what to search)],[Compare As VbCompareMethod])
Evaluate(Name)
Ubound(array) / Lbound(array)
```